# Rails twitter bootstrap generator trying to use couch_rest model instead of normal active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, couchrest

I generated a scaffold as usual:

```
rails g scaffold Job description:text user_id:integer finished:boolean
rake db:migrate
```

But after that, the bootstrap layout generator is trying to use couchrest_model it seems:

```
/Users/cblair/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/couchrest_model-1.1.2/lib/couchrest/model/base.rb:82:in `method_missing': undefined method `columns' for Job:Class (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/cblair/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.2.0/lib/generators/bootstrap/themed/themed_generator.rb:87:in `block in retrieve_columns'
    from /Users/cblair/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.2.0/lib/generators/bootstrap/themed/themed_generator.rb:101:in `rescue_block'
    from /Users/cblair/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.2.0/lib/generators/bootstrap/themed/themed_generator.rb:86:in `retrieve_columns'
    from /Users/cblair/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.2.0/lib/generators/bootstrap/themed/themed_generator.rb:58:in `columns'
```

I use couchrest for stuff, but not Active Record. (I basically call a few GET and POST methods in it).

My first question is, how can I set the default ORM so maybe the bootstrap generator will pick up on it? I've also tried this:

```
rails g bootstrap:themed Jobs fluid --orm=active_record
```

~but I get the same error, seems to ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Ah ha, I realized I should have done this:

```
rails g scaffold Job description:text user_id:integer finished:boolean --orm=active_record
```

Without the --orm option on the initial scaffold gen caused it to be a CouchRest active record, and the Job class in the model file was extended by CouchRest:Model:Base. Re-generating the scaffold fixed the problem. The bootstrap generator now uses the correct version of AR.